# Getting a warning when use objectmapper in flux inappropriate blocking method call in java reactor

Tags: spring-webflux, objectmapper, reactor

i am new to reactor, i tried to create a flux from Iterable. then i want to convert my object into string by using object mapper. then the ide warns a message like this in this part of the code `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event)`. the message `Inappropriate blocking method call`. there is no compile error. could you suggest a solution.

```java
        Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(new Event(), new Event()))
                .flatMap(event -> {
                    try {
                        return Mono.just(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event));
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        return Mono.error(e);
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(jsonStrin -> {
                    System.out.println("jsonStrin = " + jsonStrin);
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you an answer, but I don't pretty sure this is what you want. it seems like block the thread. so then you can't get the exact benefits of reactive if you block the thread. that's why the IDE warns you. you can create the mono with `monoSink`. like below.

```java
        AtomicReference<ObjectMapper> objectMapper = new AtomicReference<>(new ObjectMapper());
        Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(new Event(), new Event()))
                .flatMap(event -> {
                    return Mono.create(monoSink -> {
                        try {
                            monoSink.success(objectMapper .writeValueAsString(event));
                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            monoSink.error(e);
                        }
                    });

                })
                .cast(String.class) // this cast will help you to axact data type that you want to continue the pipeline
                .subscribe(jsonString -> {
                    System.out.println("jsonString = " + jsonString);
                });
```

please try out this method and check that error will be gone.

it doesn't matter if `objectMapper` is be a normal java object as you did. (if you don't change). it is not necessary for your case.

Comment: This is ugly and not a solution. Blocking calls should be placed on their own scheduler so they dont block execution. Atomic references should be avoided. Downvoted.

Comment: @Toerktumlare So, what is your suggestion regarding OP's logic?

Comment: Blocking calls should be handled in accordance to the reference documentation https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking
If you use AtomicReferences, you are sharing memory between threads, hence creating state, and threads and keeping states is very bad. OP has given too little information, so one should ask about more info about the service, the consumer, etc. Is this a spring boot service? what does the api look like? etc, it needs more context. As soon as you need to use Atomic references in reactor, its a direct code smell.

Answer (score -3):

You need to do it like this:

```
     Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(new Event(), new Event()))
     .flatMap(event -> {
        try {
             return Mono.just(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(event));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return Mono.error(e);
        }
     })
     .subscribe(jsonStrin -> {
         System.out.println("jsonStrin = " + jsonStrin);
     });
```

Comment: what is the defiance between my code and the code that you summited? I can't see a  defiance ?

Comment: The code I posted works fine for me.